# Can't goto SPA page route when typing route manually in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, vue-router, single-page-application, static-files

So far, I made the following setup:

- Created project in Ruby on Rails 7
- Created Vue project as a directory inside the `app` directory of rails
- The Vue project is based on: Vue3, Vue-router and Vuex
- I configured the Vue project on build to output in Rails `pubic/spa` directory, i.e. serve the SPA app in the static files
- So far so good, when I run Rails and build the Vue project, everything is working as expected
- When I click on a link on the Vue page, I'm expectedly going to the desired page
- However, if I refresh on a routed page (e.g. `spa/about`) Rails throws Routing Error
- In addition, if I try typing the route manually, I get the Routing Error again.

I'm figuring that I need a way to tell Rails to always redirect to the SPA app every time the route prefix is `spa`

**Is there a way to config rails to do that?**

something like this (in `route.rb`)

```
# every URL prefix is with spa, redirect to static file `spa/index.html`
get "spa#*" => "spa#*"
# or maybe like this?
prefix :spa # there's no `prefix` method option obviously
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out with some digging and testing.
Here's how you config Rails:

#### 1st Create a controller with a single action

```
class SpaController < ApplicationController
    def index
        render file: "#{Rails.root}/public/spa/index.html", layout: false
    end
end
```

#### 2nd config `route.rb` with the new contoller

In `route.rb` file, add the following line

`get 'spa/*path', :to => 'spa#index'`

##### explanation

The wild card `*path` is used to catch any "action" while the `spa` is served as my prefix as I desired in the beginning.

So for example:

- `http://localhost:3000/spa/about`
- `http://localhost:3000/spa/home`

All of these routes will be redirect to the same action `index` in my `SpaController`.
In the case of Vue-router, it knows how to handle the routing from there.

I have not tried the same solution on other SPA frameworks (e.g. Angular), but I think this solution can work with them as well.

Happy frontend program

Comment: This is not an efficient solution - you're using Rails to simply serve up a static HTML file a which is something that NGinX or Apache can do way more efficiently. Sure - it may fix your immediate problem but its like using a sword to open a bag of chips.

Comment: I talked with team manager about your solution in my company. He said the same thing.
Since I'm a Full-Stack develop, I'm less aware of the other tools (such as NGinX and IIS) out side of web application's tool, i.e. Rails ASP.NET etc... .

Can you please provide your solution as well, for example with NGinX?
I would like to learn about tools beyond the web frameworks.

Comment: You're going to have to ask your devops about that one. Depends entirely on your setup.